# How to iterate more efficiency with multiple IF statements Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 3 if statements and they are really ugly in terms of style and efficiency.

They parse HTML with BS4. 
HTML is in example_post variable.
If element exists -> get text 
If does not exist -> assign 'None' as a str.

```
if example_post.find('span', class_='tag1'):
    post_reactions = example_post.find('span', class_='tag1').getText()
else:
    post_reactions = 'None'


if example_post.find('span', class_='tag2'):
    post_comments = example_post.find('span', class_='tag2').getText()
else:
    post_comments = 'None'

if example_post.find('span', class_='tag3'):
    post_shares = example_post.find('span', class_= 'tag3').getText()
else:
    post_shares = 'None'
```

I started to google how to make it better and found that it is possible to use dictionaries with if statements

so the dict

post_reactions_dict = {'post_reactions': 'tag1', 'post_comments':'tag2','post_shares':'tag3'}

and tried like this

```
post_titles = []
post_values = []

for key,value in post_reactions_dict.items():
    if example_post.find('span', class_=key):
        post_values.append(example_post.find('span', class_=key).getText())
        post_titles.append(key)
    else:
        post_titles.append(key)
        post_values.append('None')
```

It is ok, but maybe it is possible to make it even better?

Ideal result:

```
post_titles = ['post_reactions', 'post_comments', 'post_shares']
post_values (it depends) but for the question ['None', 'None', 'None']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
post = {}
attributes = ('reactions', 'tag1'), ('comments', 'tag2'), ('shares', 'tag3')

for attribute, tag in attributes:
    try:
        post[attribute] = example_post.find('span', class_=tag).getText()
    except AttributeError:
        post[attribute] = None
```

1. Don't use individual variables, use a dict to store the data.
2. Figure out what the variables (the differences between your repeated code) are; in this case it's just `post_*` and `tag*`, put them as pairs together as data.
3. Don't repeat the `example_post.find(...)` call; here we're using the fact that `.getText()` will likely cause an `AttributeError` if `find()` returns `None`/`False`/whatever it is it returns.

Comment: Catching AttributeError is risky, this will hide mistakes like mispelling method names.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making this a bit more generic and avoid using exceptions as the "normal" program flow:

```
def get_span(element,class_):
    tag = element.find('span', class_=class_)
    return None if tag is None else tag.getText()

post_reactions = get_span(example_post,'tag1')
post_comments  = get_span(example_post,'tag2')
post_share     = get_span(example_post,'tag3')
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume the .find() method returns a class or None? If so my approach without any if:

```
def get_text(class_):
    try:
        return example_post.find('span', class_=class_).getText()
    except AttributeError:
        return 'None'

 post_reactions = get_text('tag1')
 post_comments = get_text('tag2')
 post_share = get_text('tag3')
```

Comment: Same objection as deceze's answer.